# OCI8 + Activerecord, How to create trigger

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rails-activerecord, oci8, sinatra-activerecord

I've been dealing with this problem. 
I'm working with active record + OCI8 + Sinatra, And I'm not able to run migrations (because I have not access to admin user on database, but I could send queries to my oracle admin).

This is my model

```
class Modify < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.sequence_name = "PRM_W01.seq_modifies"
  belongs_to :parameter
end
```

But when I tried to create a new user I had this output

```
D, [2015-08-31T16:50:34.636767 #4696] DEBUG -- :   Primary Key (7.5ms)  SELECT cc.column_name FROM all_constraints c, all_cons_columns cc WHERE c.owner = 'PRM_W01' AND c.table_name = 'MODIFIES' AND c.constraint_type = 'P' AND cc.owner = c.owner AND cc.constraint_name = c.constraint_name
D, [2015-08-31T16:50:34.639891 #4696] DEBUG -- :   Primary Key Trigger (2.5ms)            SELECT trigger_name
          FROM all_triggers
          WHERE owner = 'PRM_W01'
            AND trigger_name = 'MODIFIES_PKT'
            AND table_owner = 'PRM_W01'
            AND table_name = 'MODIFIES'
            AND status = 'ENABLED'

OCIError: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

I was reading [this](http://oracle-enhanced.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/OracleEnhancedAdapter.html#M000032)

> Create primary key trigger (so that you can skip primary key value in
>   INSERT statement). By default trigger name will be “table_name_pkt“,
>   you can override the name with :trigger_name option (but it is not
>   recommended to override it as then this trigger will not be detected
>   by ActiveRecord model and it will still do prefetching of sequence
>   value).

So I think that my problem is that I didn't create that trigger, but I don't know how to migration does, could anybody help me to get that code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this creating this trigger on db.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  PRM_W01.MODIFIES_PKT
BEFORE INSERT ON PRM_W01.MODIFIES FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF inserting THEN
IF :new.id IS NULL THEN
SELECT PRM_W01.SEQ_MODIFIES.NEXTVAL INTO :new.id FROM dual;
END IF;
END IF;
END;
```

I read code from [oracle-enhanced](https://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced/blob/f1b68b2bae8c10aac8c2e619a27d9bb755fcfd0c/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced/schema_statements.rb#L523-L532) to create it.

Another cool thing that I found in order to get an oracle running on my own developer environment was [this docker image](https://github.com/wnameless/docker-oracle-xe-11g)